# Disabling mobile media queries when using zurb foundation

Tags: media-queries, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to disable the mobile media queries when using the foundation framework. I saw that they updated the framework to include the ability to disable the media queries: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/865.

I see the include in my `app.scss` for the media queries

`//@import "foundation/components/modules/mqueries";`

But as you can see it is commented out.

It works when I delete the `@media` queries in the compiled css, but for obvious reasons I'm not going to do this.

Comment: do you mean that commenting out the line is not working for you?

Comment: Yeah, its was already commented out but it is still putting in the `@media` queries for mobile

Answer (score 0):

The app.scss file uses all of Foundation by default. If you want to disable some items, you have to cherry pick the items you want to keep.

You probably have an

```
@import "foundation"
```

at the top of your file. That should be removed and then you should start uncommenting the items you would like to keep (it is described like that in the app.scss file actually).